# Send data to firebase (HttpClient)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to update firebase data (Realtime Database) to a specific table.
And i don't know how to do it. With the code I did, the table [TB_MyProfile_Composite] is overwrite and not updated.

there is the code to update the data

```
sendData(data: CompositeOtherModel[]) {
    return this.http.put(this._URL, data);
  }
```

That how the table is before the update:

[image: Before update]

That how it is after the update. The table TB_MyProfile_Composite has been overwrite :(

[image: After update]

Thanks for your help !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your using the firebase REST API, all you need to do is change the URL that you are using.

If you're hitting the `https://firebase-id.web.app/DB_Profile collection.json`, the accessing your `TB_MyProfile_Composite` collection simply change your url to be something like `https://firebase-id.web.app/DB_Profile collection/TB_MyProfile_Composite.json`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes I'm using REST API. Your recommendation resolved the problem. Now I will check how to add the the table name to the url without re-writing the all url. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Angular, i suggest you to use AngularFire to manage your firebase services.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

Comment: Thanks for the information. In my case i just use firebase to make a test, so I didn't want to install the farebase package. But your information is very useful, thank you !!!! :)